# Dividing each item of a row by a specific value

Tags: r

I want to divide each entry in a row by a particular number that is contained in a column within the same data frame.

Lets say we have a data frame having 6 columns and 3 rows with the last column having the numbers I want to use as a denominator :

```
A <- c(4, 5, 10)
B <- c(8, 45, 2)
C <- c(7, 4, 0)
D <- c(98, 32, 12)
E <- c(1, 3, 11)

df <- data.frame(A, B, C, D, E)
df$particular_number<-c(22, 34, 23)
```

Now I would like to divide each entry of row 1 and columns A - E by 22 and so on (each entry for row 2 and columns A - E by 34; each entry for row 3 and columns A - E by 23).

In the end I want to have the computed items in a new data frame with same dimensions, but having the calculated entries.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```r
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[,.SD/particular_number]
#>            A          B         C         D          E particular_number
#> 1: 0.1818182 0.36363636 0.3181818 4.4545455 0.04545455                 1
#> 2: 0.1470588 1.32352941 0.1176471 0.9411765 0.08823529                 1
#> 3: 0.4347826 0.08695652 0.0000000 0.5217391 0.47826087                 1
```

<sup>Created on 2021-06-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

Using `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
df <- df %>%
      mutate(across(A:E, ~ ./particular_number))
df
#          A          B         C         D          E particular_number
#1 0.1818182 0.36363636 0.3181818 4.4545455 0.04545455                22
#2 0.1470588 1.32352941 0.1176471 0.9411765 0.08823529                34
#3 0.4347826 0.08695652 0.0000000 0.5217391 0.47826087                23
```

Answer (score 0):

You can directly divide `particular_number` column with all the columns in the dataframe. If `particular_number` column is last in your dataframe you can ignore that using `-ncol(df)`.

```
df[-ncol(df)] <- df[-ncol(df)]/df$particular_number
df

#      A     B     C     D      E particular_number
#1 0.182 0.364 0.318 4.455 0.0455                22
#2 0.147 1.324 0.118 0.941 0.0882                34
#3 0.435 0.087 0.000 0.522 0.4783                23
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option, although perhaps not as tidy, is
`rbind((df[1,]/22), (df[2,]/34), (df[3,]/23))`
or a bit more generally as
`rbind(df[1,1:5]/df[1,6], df[2,1:5]/df[2,6], df[3,1:5]/df[3,6])`